# Align table entries with s-columns

Tags: tables

I'm looking to create a table in which I align the entries by the dot. For the first column of entry values, this alignment takes place nicely. However, for  the second column, the negative value surrounded by square-brackets is shifted so that the dots do not align. Any suggestions how to solve this?

```
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{1}{l}*{3}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
\toprule
\toprule
        & {$\alpha$} & {$\beta$} & {$R^{2}$}\\
        \midrule
                        Credit Spread & 0.00  & 0.13  & 0.00\\
 &\hbox{[$0.26$]}  & \hbox{[$-5.56$]}  & \\
  \addlinespace 

       \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why are you using these hboxes? To disable the effects of the S column?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) it is custom here to post full minimal examples, not sniplets like this. Full minimal examples can then be copied as is and tested. (3) Why are you using those `\hbox` in the first place? They of course messes things us and the S parser cannot see the dot. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? I've never seen that syntax before.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'm assuming you are trying to do

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp!]
  \centering

  \sisetup{
    parse-numbers=false,
  }

  \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
  \begin{tabular}{
      l
      S[table-format=2.3] % space for []'s
      S[table-format=-2.3] % 
      S[table-format=1.3] % 
    }
    \toprule
    & \mc{$\alpha$} & \mc{$\beta$} & \mc{$R^{2}$}
    \\
    \midrule
    Credit Spread & 0.00       & 0.13      & 0.00
    \\
    & [0.26]     & [-5.56]   & 
    \\
    \addlinespace 

    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reserve space for the brackets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Whatever}

\sisetup{
  table-space-text-pre=[,
  table-space-text-post=],
}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
}
\toprule
        & {$\alpha$} & {$\beta$} & {$R^{2}$}\\
\midrule
Credit Spread &  0.00  &   0.13  & 0.00 \\
              & [0.26] & [-5.56] &      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]